# Dataframe getting all data in one 'cell'

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm having some problems to put the data I want in a specific `df` .

When I print the value without `df` i get

[link to image bc if i type the answer it doesn't shows up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KfFWW.png)

Then I try to use pandas dataframe to insert it in a dataframe and I get:

```
dinner = pd.DataFrame([dinner])
dinner.head()
```

> Home Made - Tuna Poke, 472 gm (4 Ounces) {'cal...

So, basically, everything gets in just one cell. I would like to get something like:

```
        A                  |     Calories | carbohydrates
 Home made - tuna poke     |    592       |   8
```

Does anyone know how can I do it?

Comment: can you provide a working minimal example?

Comment: What is `dinner`? A string?

Comment: [mcve] is what people need in order to help you

Answer (score 0):

`dinner` looks like a string parsed from html text. If it is the case and there is regular pattern for parsing data, then the following code may work.

```
nutritions = dinner.split('{')[1].split('}')[0].split(', ')
menu = dinner.split('{')[0].strip('<').strip()
dict_dinner = {}
for n in nutritions:
    item, qty = n.split(': ')
    dict_dinner[item.strip("'")] = qty

df = pd.DataFrame(dict_dinner, index=[menu])
print(df)
```

This outputs:
[image]